# How to center a cupertino icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

First of all, I have tried using Center(),
With that out the way, it seems cupertino icons are off center

```
             IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.add_circled,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {}
              ),
```

wrapping the icon directly in a Center() widget doesnt change anything either I this is how it looks [image: slightly off center]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CupertinoIcons are actually centered in Flutter.

If you take a look at the source icons map for Cupertino [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/cupertino_icons/master/map.png) you'll see that the icons are aligned to the bottom inside the square that Flutter loads (and even slightly aligned to the left). Therefore, you can't adjust it's alignment in your code as the resource is already centered.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I went a step further and found the CupertinoIcons.ttf font on the flutter sdk source. Then opened it with https://www.glyphrstudio.com.

[image]

Then did the same with MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf

[image]

You can clearly see how the icon is aligned against the baseline on Cupertino (as characters do on any font), and perfectly centered on Material (as icons should be).

There's more information about font metrics on [this Medium article](https://proandroiddev.com/android-and-typography-101-5f06722dd611)

You can find CupertinoIcons.ttf here: https://github.com/flutter/cupertino_icons/tree/master/assets

Comment: i think i know what your trying to say but they're not 'centered' and i guess what your actually saying is that they shouldn't be, as this is what they are in iOS

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is actually by iOS design or not. But the link I posted is the source Flutter use. If we talk about centering the icon, it is centered. But because it is not trimmed it looks like it isn't

Comment: sorry but i don't agree

Comment: @martinseal1987 I've updated my answer with more prove of what I'm saying. Please take a look.

Comment: cool, so i was right to say they are off center, as you also concluded they are aligned on the baseline like an icon font, so it will never be centered

Comment: That's right. The icons are not centered at typography level, but they are at Flutter level.

Comment: Hi, I faced the same problem of my icon not centralised as well. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: My sugesstion is to use an icons font that place them centered. If you put your text and icon in a row, and padding around the icon you might get a workaround, but see if it renders correctly in any screen density on both android and ios.